# how to change the color of an element that is in front of a background image in css?

Tags: css

I put a background image in the body. I also have a different color for my menu box. I don't want to see the image in the menu box, how can I do that in CSS? Below is my code.

Thank you,

Avi

```
body{
    font-family: sans-serif;
    background-image: url("coffee_beans.jpeg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
}
.menu{
    position: relative;
    border: 2px solid red;
    max-width: 613px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: rgba(255, 189, 109, 0.395);    
}
```

Comment: Are you looking to add a `fill` to `.menu`?

Comment: I'm a bit confused - if you don't want to see the image in the menu box why is there a semi transparent rather than an opqque background on menu?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to remove the background-color alpha, it will not become transparent background.

```
.menu{
    background-color: rgb(255, 189, 109);    
}
```

If you must keep the background-color for transparent, you may create one more layer on the .menu div

```css
body{
    font-family: sans-serif;
    background-image: url("https://dl.fujifilm-x.com/global/products/cameras/x-t3/sample-images/ff_x_t3_002.JPG");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
}

.menub{
  position: relative;
    border: 2px solid red;
    max-width: 613px;
    width: 100%;
    height:100px;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: white;
}

.menu{
    width: 100%;
    height:100px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 189, 109,0.382);    
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="menub">
    <div class="menu"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```